# How to execute Chown -r linux statement in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

Can you please help me in executing 
chown -R linux statement in windows batch scripting.

Thanks and Best Regards,
Aman

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly? There is no chown command in Windows. Maybe `subinacl` will do what you're looking for.

Comment: Hello Mori, I want to changes the permission of all files and folder of a folder to a user using command line

Comment: I've never done that kind of thing on windows, but hopefully this thread will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928738/how-to-grant-permission-to-users-for-a-directory-using-command-line-in-windows?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent is TAKEOWN

From the prompt, type

```
takeown /?
```

Most likely you'd want

```
takeown /r
```

Comment: Hello Peter,My linux command is chown -R user1:user2 folder1.How i can change the ownership of folder1 folder as well as its child files and folders to user2.

Comment: `TAKEOWN /s systemname /u userid /p passwordforuser /f target /r` would seem to be appropriate - it worked for me. `/p password` is only required if the user has a password, `/u userid` if it's not the current user taing posession, `/s systemname` (as in `/s \\your-pc` if it's a remote PC or you use the /u switch. Simply `takeown /f target` takes posession for the current user, the `/r` switch recurses through a target directory. You can also use /a to assign ownership to the administrators' group rather than the current user.